# nginx on docker reverse proxied to wordpress container not loading javascripts

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup nginx docker container which is on same network as 2 wordpress site containers. This is the nginx.conf file

```
worker_processes 512;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    upstream informatica_site {
        server InformaticaSite:80;
    }

    upstream informatica_blog {
        server InformaticaBlog:80;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name informaticasystems.xom;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://informatica_site;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name blog.informaticasystems.xom;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://informatica_blog;
        }
    }
}
```

host file

```
127.0.0.1   informaticasystems.xom
127.0.0.1   blog.informaticasystems.xom
```

but when im composing up, javascript files are not properly loading

[image]

they are trying to reach proxy_pass instead of actual server name.

Just a clarification, nginx and wordpress sites are all in docker containers on same network, I am accessing from my browser in my local machine(outside docker)

```
version: '3'
services:
  InformaticaSite:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ******
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ******
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ******
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ******
    volumes:
      - ./informatica_site:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - informatica_network


  InformaticaBlog:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ******
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ******
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ******
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ******
    volumes:
      - ./informatica_blog:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    networks:
      - informatica_network


  informatica_site_db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ******
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ******
      MYSQL_USER: ******
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ******
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_site_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - informatica_network


  informatica_blog_db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ******
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ******
      MYSQL_USER: ******
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ******
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_blog_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - informatica_network


  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - informatica_network


networks:
  informatica_network:
```

according to what i have been able to search proxy_pass is not suppose to do this, i am new to nginx so might have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using the following `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes 512;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    upstream informatica_site {
        server InformaticaSite:80;
    }

    upstream informatica_blog {
        server InformaticaBlog:80;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name informaticasystems.xom;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://informatica_site;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name blog.informaticasystems.xom;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://informatica_blog;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

That way nginx as a proxy puts the originally requested url inside the X-Forwarded-For header. Wordpress reads it and creates its links depending on that value. Before wordpress got the request by nginx and had only that one to work with. Now you pass the values of the original request (to nginx) to wordpress.

Comment: This solved the problem, can you expand on why it worked